# Text Schema File - Need to allow for different size strings inside tags

Tags: xml, regex, schema

I am writing a Text Schema browser using a tool that helps me to create fields and all that stuff.
I have a portion of an XML file coming in, and everything is a fixed size except for a memo field. I would like to specify an expression that will allow for any length strings terminated by a new XML tag.

Here is what the input will look like:

```
...<Memo>test rate</Memo>...
```

I want the schema file to know that the actual memo field value is terminated by the `<` of the XML tag.

Here are the default regex expressions that I can choose from:

```
[^,\n]+
[^\n]+
[^ ]+
[^,]+
```

If I take the first one and replace the `\n` with a `<`, will that work?

What is a good expression that will work?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that will capture everything between XML tags ?

Comment: @Sniffer - If I understand what you mean, I think that is what I want. I want everything between the ending '>' of the Memo start tag and the beginning '<' of the Memo end tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regular expression:

```
<Memo>([^<]*)<
```

This will capture what you want in group 1.